# what can I use to create a game for iphone like DOODLE LAUNCH?

Tags: iphone

Hey, I just downloaded this game doodle launch today and I think its pretty cool, I would like to make a similar game using some sort of engine? it has physics and it uses the iPhone tilt controls... any suggestions??

This is the link in case you want to check it out...:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-launch/id393793976?mt=8

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2D is a popular, fairly easy-to-use game engine:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

It doesn't have physics by default, but many people add the Box2D physics engine:

http://www.box2d.org/

Here's a clear tutorial on using the two together on iOS:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls